# search and load system font using xcode in c++

Tags: c++, xcode

Do anyone know what functions I can use to load system fonts on mac? I found examples using cocoa, but not for c++ code. Thanks.

The font will be used to write to GUI. Should I load system font or should I embed a font to the project then load it? Thanks for any suggestions.

LJ